# Strange loading error

Tags: jquery, web

I have strange problem with fade in script. I used this code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#col3').delay(1500).fadeIn('3000');
$('.column-3').delay(1500).fadeIn('3000');
});
```

It seems fine, but sometimes its not loading ;) Here is the [website](http://greenlevel.pl/uslugi/pozycjonowanie).

Comment: Did you wrap it in `$(document).ready` function? could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#col3').delay(1500).fadeIn('3000');
   $('.column-3').delay(1500).fadeIn('3000');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a timeout for setTimeout call. If you want to delay the animation until the DOM is loaded, put your script in `onDomLoaded` event handler:

```
$(function(){
   $('#col3').delay(1500).fadeIn('3000');
   $('.column-3').delay(1500).fadeIn('3000');
});
```